# Select column from table number of times by defined condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, union, recursive-query

Need to select record number of times by condition so each ID needs to be selected number of qty time

Example:

```
ID |qty |column_A
1   13   12/31/2020
2   25   1/1/2021
3   34   1/2/2021
4   198  1/3/2021
5   97   1/4/2021
```

Output expected:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
...
```

Note:

```
qty=DATEDIFF(MONTH,'date',z.column A)+1
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: sqlserver, mysql, oracle...?

Answer (score 2):

One option uses a recursive query. In standard SQL, you would phrase this as:

```
with recursive cte (id, qty) (
    select id, qty from mytable
    union all
    select id, qty - 1 from cte where qty > 0
)
select id from cte order by id
```

Comment: Wonderful!!! Thank you... added option (maxrecursion 0) at the end since some id qty more than 100. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: How to add Month

with recursive cte (id, qty, Forecast_date) (
    select id, qty, StartDate from mytable
    union all
    select id, qty - 1, eomonth(dateadd(month, 1,Forecast_date)) from cte where qty > 0
)
select id from cte order by id

Output:

Comment: @Andrey_Kirillov: you might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this.